# Jira + Dashboard: Rudimentary views in new dashboard?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

we want to create a rudimentary dashboard for a client in Jira. Only certain items like epics and defects should be displayed.

- only epics and defects should be displayed in the overview
- when creating a new epic, we want to be able to select different types (similar to a ticket that can also be selected as story, defect, change request, etc.):
- a.   Old Scope
- b.   New functions

The question here:

- Can I do this normally using filters?
- Do I have to go to the administration options?
- What do I have to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> only epics and defects should be displayed in the overview

Shouldn't be a problem. Create a filter that selects only epics and defects and then use the filter results gadget on the dashboard. Or two separate filters if you want them displayed separately.

> when creating a new epic, we want to be able to select different types (similar to a ticket that can also be selected as story, defect, change request, etc.)

I'm afraid this will require administrator privileges. You will need to create a custom field and add it to epics.